# CDI not working after migration to Java EE 7

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

I recently migrated a simple `Java EE 6` project to `Java EE 7`. In detail this means I just changed the dependency from `javax:javaee-api:6.0` to `javax:javaee-api:7.0` and deployed it to `Glassfish 4` instead of `Glassfish 3`.

Afterwards the application did not work anymore, because `CDI` could not inject the annoted dependencies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was, that I did not know that the `deployment descriptor` and also the default behaviour to find dependencies has changed in `Java EE 7`.

The new `deployment descriptor (beans.xml)` has to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       version="1.1" bean-discovery-mode="all" >
</beans>
```

Important is the attribute `bean-discovery-mode`, which configures how `CDI` finds all the dependencies. With setting it to `bean-discovery-mode="all"`, `CDI` behaves like in `Java EE 6`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `bean-discovery-mode="all"` works, but could also be set to `"annotated"` depending on how your beans are set up.

Or you could eliminate `beans.xml` altogether to create an implicit archive. See the [Java EE 7 Tutorial section on packaging CDI applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-adv001.htm). To use implicit archives, you need a scope-defining annotation on your beans.

Answer (score 2):

To get rid of the beans.xml file and make your injections work on Glassfish 4, you have to change the packages of the scopes as well:

```
javax.faces.bean.ApplicationScoped -> javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped
javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped -> javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped -> javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped
javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped -> javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
```